# User Sign in form and a 'I am not a robot capcha' in a DialogFlow chatbot

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am not able to find a way to add a user Sign in form as a response from the agent  to register the user. Also I need to integrate a 'I am not a robot' checkbox in the form.
I tried 'Custom payload' but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how your chatbot being presented to the user, and which integration you might be using.

If you're using an integration such as Facebook Messenger or the Google Assistant, you'll have to defer to that platform's authentication mechanism. For example, with the Google Assistant you can use [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/), and Facebook Messenger has [a similar feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/account-linking/).

If your chatbot is embedded directly in your own frontend, you'll need to write your own mechanism for sign-in.